# Show entire Bottom sheet with toolbar when keyboard is visible

Tags: java, android, xml, android-dialogfragment, android-bottomsheetdialog

in my application i have 'bottom sheet dialog fragment' when i open it, it work fine, like below image:

[image: Here is the image]

but when keyboard is visible the upper toolbar disappear, like below image show.

[image: Second image]

My Question is how to make toolbar always visible even when keybord is visible....

Here is my '"sheet bottom xml"'

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:background="@color/grey_5"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/bt_close"
              android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"
              app:tint="@color/grey_80" />


          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/save"
              android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border"
              app:tint="@color/grey_80" />


          <ImageButton
              android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_repeat"
              app:tint="@color/grey_80" />

          <ImageButton
              android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"                
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert"
              app:tint="@color/grey_80" />

      </LinearLayout>

  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/app_bar_layout2"
      android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:scrollbars="none"
      android:scrollingCache="true"
      app:layout_behavior=
      "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="@dimen/spacing_large">

          <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
              android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_recycler_comment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              tools:itemCount="10" />

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/lyt_spacer"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:visibility="gone">

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                  android:text="No comments yet"
                  android:textSize="22dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

          </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      android:paddingBottom="10dp"
      android:scrollbars="none"
      android:scrollingCache="true"
      app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center">


      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/post_view_enter_comment_edit_Text"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_margin="4dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/edit_text_round_bg"
          android:hint="Write comment..."
          android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
          android:maxLength="400"
          android:maxLines="5"
          android:textColor="@color/black"
          android:textSize="17sp"/>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/post_view_send_comment"
          android:layout_width="40dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
          android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
          android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_grey_300"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:padding="4dp"
          android:paddingStart="6dp"
          android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />


  </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And also here my "BottomFragment.java".

```
 public class FragmentBottomSheetDialogFull extends 
   BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior;
    private AppBarLayout app_bar_layout;
    private RelativeLayout parent_lyt;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TopicRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> topicsArrayList, selectedArray;

    ConstraintLayout sheet_constraint_layout;

    private String Post_id;
    private String content;
    private String topic;

    public void setData(String post_id, String post_content, 
    String topic) {

        this.Post_id = post_id;
        this.content = post_content;
        this.topic = topic;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) 
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        final View view = View.inflate(getContext(), 
        R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet_dialog_full, null);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, 
        R.style.DialogStyle);

        dialog.setContentView(view);
        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) 
        view.getParent());
        
 mBehavior.setPeekHeight(BottomSheetBehavior.PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO);

        app_bar_layout = (AppBarLayout) 
        view.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
        parent_lyt = (RelativeLayout) 
        view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);

        mBehavior.setMaxHeight((Tools.getScreenHeight() / 2) + 
        100);

        recyclerView = 
        view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_recycler_comment);

        topicsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            topicsArrayList.add("my " + i);
        }

        adapter = new TopicRecyclerAdapter(topicsArrayList, 
        selectedArray);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
        LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    
        mBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new 
        BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View 
        bottomSheet, int newState) {

              
              

                if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN == 
     newState) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, 
     float slideOffset) {

            }
        });

        ((ImageButton) 
     view.findViewById(R.id.bt_close)).setOnClickListener(new 
     View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }


    private void hideView(View view) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 0;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        //  dismiss();
        // dismissAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    private void showView(View view, int size) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = size;

        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private int getActionBarSize() {
        final TypedArray styledAttributes = 
    getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] 
   {android.R.attr.actionBarSize});
        int size = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
        return size;
    }


}
```

What exactly i seek to achieve is shown in this image, the toolbar is stable despite keyboard is visible or not.

[image: third image]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is to make specific style for that inside **styles.xml**

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible</item>
```

Once we can't initialize any fragment or BottomSheetDialogFragment inside our manifest, the best way is to go to styles.xml (DialogStyle) and and make

```
<item name="android:windowsSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible</item>
```

After that we should override onCreate inside our **FragmentBottomSheetDialog.java**

```
override void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle);

}
```

this works prefectly

Thanks for @hardik-kotadiya

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to initialize your activity in manifest.

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Activities"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"/>
```

The most convenient way that I found to change this is by creating style:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
```

And set this in onCreate method of your BottomSheetDialogFragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle)}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Once we can't initialize any fragment or  BottomSheetDialogFragment inside our manifest..the best way is to go to styles.xml (DialogStyle) and and make `<item name="android:windowsSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible</item>` ... this works prefectly